# What is a LESS sourcemap?

Tags: css, less

I refer to the LESS tutorial here:
    http://lesscss.org/usage/index.html#programmatic-usage

Could someone explain to me what a sourcemap is? What is its use? When and how do we use a sourcemap?

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) post useful. (though its for JS, its analogous to LESS/CSS)

Comment: http://www.thecssninja.com/talks/sourcemaps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since LESS is compiled, a sourcemap allows you to trace the compiled CSS back to the original source(s) - which may consist of multiple partials. This is vital for debugging issues in the compiled CSS.

The sourcemap is JSON format and contains references to the original file(s) you used when compiling to CSS.  Those might include files written with LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript, etc.

Here's a good overview:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-source-maps-for-better-preprocessor-debugging--cms-22735

And this is also a good read:

http://pburtchaell.com/2014/using-source-maps/

Answer (score 2):

When you use a pre-processor like LESS, the result CSS file may include an error due to an error in the original LESS file. When such error is detected on the web browser, the browser can point to the line number in the CSS file, but that is useless for debugging the LESS file. A sourcemap is a mechanism/file to keep the location information of the original LESS file so that the browser can point to the location in the LESS file when an error is detected in the CSS file.